# I want to use inner join on data table's consisting of three different data table and return result as consolidated data table using c #

Tags: c#, linq

Table 1:Parent  {     Columns: ParentId ,       Name  }

Table 2:Child   {     Columns: ChildId  ,       ChildName }

Table 3:Relationship {Columns: RelationshipId , PrimaryId(ParentId) ,SecondaryId(Child Id)}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
           DataTable parentTable = new DataTable();
           parentTable.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(string));
           parentTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

           DataTable childTable = new DataTable();
           childTable.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(string));
           childTable.Columns.Add("ChildNameName", typeof(string));

           DataTable relationshipTable = new DataTable();
           relationshipTable.Columns.Add("RelationshipId", typeof(string));
           relationshipTable.Columns.Add("PrimaryId", typeof(string));
           relationshipTable.Columns.Add("SecondaryId", typeof(string));

           var results = (from r in relationshipTable.AsEnumerable()
                          join p in parentTable.AsEnumerable() on r.Field<string>("PrimaryId") equals p.Field<string>("ParentId")
                          join c in childTable.AsEnumerable() on r.Field<string>("SecondaryId") equals c.Field<string>("ChildID")
                          select new { r = r, p = p, c = c })
                         .ToList();
```